# Checkbox list need to be checked based on the values saved in DB

Tags: c#

```
chkTypeofIncident.DataSource = from t2 in        
                   dbl.usp_GetIncidentsType().AsQueryable() 
                   where t2.IncidentTypeFlag== '2' select t2; 

chkTypeofIncident.DataTextField = "Incidents";
chkTypeofIncident.DataValueField = "IncidentsMasterID";
chkTypeofIncident.DataBind();
```

I got the selected values using LINQ. but output was it always checked the last value in database.

```
var CheckedInc = from t2 in dbl.usp_GetIncidentsTypeDetail(Convert.ToInt32(HiddenIncidentRegisterID.Value)).AsQueryable() 
                 select t2;
foreach(var chk in CheckedInc)
{                       
    chkTypeofIncident.SelectedValue = chk.IncidentsMasterID.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: chkTypeofIncident is a id of checkboxlist. suppose the query result was 1, 2 and 3 means. I want to checked all the values but now it check only last value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var chk in CheckedInc)
{
chkTypeofIncident.Items.FindByValue(chk.IncidentsMasterID).Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 chkTypeofIncident.SelectedValue = CheckedInc.FirstOrDefault().IncidentsMasterID.ToString(); 
 //here you also can use where condition
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it checked only the first value. I want to checked all the values saved in database

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!